# Vector tiles for Oracle Spatial

Tags: oracle-spatial, vector-tiles

I'm curious what solutions there may be for generating Mapbox vector tiles from SDO_Geometry data? There doesn't appear to be native support [as with PostGIS](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsMVT.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some alternatives which should work:

1) Use GeoServer vector tile output http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/vectortiles/index.html with Oracle datastore http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/database/oracle.html

2) Use MapServer vector tile output http://mapserver.org/development/rfc/ms-rfc-119.html with Oracle Spatial input http://www.mapserver.org/input/vector/oracle.html

3) Read data from Oracle with PostgreSQL by using the GDAL/OGR foreign data wrapper https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers and let PostGIS do the rest.